# Finding a certain cell in gridview through the use of column and row

Tags: gridview, datagridview, findcontrol

I have a populated gridview that consist of template fields. I would like to find/check a certain number of cells using values of rows and columns.

Eg:

---

### |Time|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|

### |1200|------|-----|-----|------|-----|

### |1300|------| -X- |-----|------|-----|

### |1400|------|-----|-----|------|-----|

lets say i have the value "1300" for the row and the column header text "col2", I would like to find the cell marked "X" and check for some condition and change the text if necessary (col1 - col5 are template fields made up of labels and buttons, so therefore base on certain conditions i would like to show/hide the labels/buttons or change the text for the labels)

Thanks

Comment: which IDE are you using?? VB6??

Comment: visual studio 2008 
language: c#

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old thread so for what it's worth:

Changing color: [Change GridView row color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp)

Show/hide a button: [Conditionally hide CommandField or ButtonField in Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview)

Hope that helps anyone else.