# How do I change color of selected Row in the Grid in C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, background-color

[image]I want to change the color of particular row selected in the grid. How is it possible for my web application? Please suggest me.

Comment: How you are selecting your row.Is it a Select Event of a Gridview?

Comment: I tried it with DataControlRowType but its not working

Comment: you need to use RowCreated-Event of the GridView. I think you need something like [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250545/how-to-implement-full-row-selecting-in-gridview-without-select-button

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-JavaScript-with-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .row-highlight
    {
        background-color: Yellow;
    }
    .row-select
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tr = $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').find('tr');

        tr.hover(
             function () {  // mouseover
                 $(this).addClass('row-highlight');
             },
             function () {  // mouseout
                 $(this).removeClass('row-highlight');
             }
        );
        tr.click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('row-select');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: are you getting any error. its working for me. you need to add the reference for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some javascript to every row in code-behind. Handle onmouseover event and change background color:
[Change GridView row color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Attach an onclick javascript function to each checkbox, and upon if the checkbox is checked, then assign some css class to that row, which will highlight the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

In your GridView, add the SelectedRowStyle-property and use the BackColor-property to set the color of the selected row.

So your GridView will look like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridTest" runat="server" DataSourceID=... >
   <Columns>
   ...
   </Columns>
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `GridView` control that we are talking about here, then you can just make use of the `<SelectedRowStyle>`

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="Server">

    <Columns></Columns>

    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedRowStyle" BackColor="LightCyan"
        ForeColor="DarkBlue"
        Font-Bold="true" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Style this up accordingly.

Comment: Kemboj - you need to also set the Selected Row index in your RowCommand.