# Set Gridview Row Background Color using value in Binding DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm having a GridView which contains a Column `ID`

I'm having a DataTable which contains two columns

```
ID
DONE
```

I'm Binding the `ID` Column in the DataTable to the GridView.
Until no Its fine.

But now I need to set the Background color of the GridView Row Basing on the `DONE` Column Value in DataTable.( If `DONE` value is `true` the Row Background Color has to be changed.)

How can I achieve this without binding the `DONE` Row to the GridView??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create `GridView1_RowDataBound` event for your GridView.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Check your condition here
    //Get Id from here and based on Id check value in the 
    //underlying dataSource Row where you have "DONE" column value
    // e.g.
    // (gridview.DataSource as DataTable), now you can find your row and cell 
    // of "Done"
    If(Condition True)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red;  // your color settings 
    }
}
```

example code snippet:

```
protected void EmployeeAvailabilityGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                  
                    if(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DONE")))
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Refer following link for more detailed implementation:
[Change GridView row color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp)

**Note**: If that row does not exist in DataSource then you must have some logic to get that from other place. May be you have `ID` as Foreign Key in another table.

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you

http://deepak-sharma.net/2012/01/27/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-rows-in-a-gridview-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-in-asp-net-3-5/

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            // determine the value of the UnitsInStock field
            if((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"strShift")).ToString() =="Alarm")
            {
                    // color the background of the row yellow
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create MyGridView _RowDataBound event for your GridView.

```
if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Check your condition here, Cells[1] for ex. is DONE/Not Done column 
    If(e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "DONE")
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green // This will make row back color green
    }
}
```

Comment: I have asked from DataBinder not from the Content in GridView Row!!

Answer (score 0):

I also solved my condition. But For Alternative row type, the background color is not set.

```
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          Label LabelStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
            if(LabelStatus.Text.Trim().ToLower().Equals("inactive"))
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            }                   

        }
```

Can you please let me know what may be the reason?

Comment: Sorry.. It works fine. It seems that css properity was overrode.