# Showing specific rows using GridView.RowDataBound Event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012, rowdatabound

**Problem**

I have a Gridview bounded to a project table having one of the attribute as clientid and other attributes. Now i want to show only specific rows where clientid is equals to a given id.

**What I have got**

1. [Change GridView row color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp)

2.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Every example seems to update the row values but none is trying what i'm trying to do.

**Second option** would be creating another data table  and insert all the rows which satisfy the condition and bound my grid view to that table.

I'm wondering if this could be done using rowdatabound event.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try Like this

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
if(check ur cobdition if condition is false)
e.Row.Visible=false;

}
```