# Dynamically apply background color of excel rows using c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have exported an excel document. In that, I have to apply the background color of the entire row based on some conditions. For example, If I have 1000 lines in the excel, I want to apply the background in 100 rows only.

I tried to set the color with range values. I am able to apply a color based on that. But I couldn't apply particular rows alone.

```
objSHT.Range["A1: A11"].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle((System.Drawing.Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString("#97C2EC"));
```

Could you please provide me the solution to apply the color in an entire row (particular row - based on column value condition)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change GridView row color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition)

Comment: What is `objSHT`?

Comment: @Liam Worksheet

Comment: @UtkarshDubey : Thanks for your reply. This was done in Grid view. But I required in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly :)

```
 for (int z=1;z<30;z++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = xlWorkSheet.Rows[z];
            row.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Azure); ;
        }
```

I was looking for that some time ago, now i figured out how to do it :D

```
var col2 = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["I:I", Type.Missing];

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range item in col2.Cells)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(item.Value) == null)
                {
                    //item.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Cyan);
                    item.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Cyan);

                }

                if (Convert.ToString(item.Value) != null)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(item.Value) == "Afterbuild")
                    {
                        item.Value = "Afterbuild";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) < 0)
                        {
                           //item.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                            item.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So, based on conditions (values) in column "I" i do change color