# How to adjust the gridview columns width after binding the datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp:GridView that binding to SQL data, how can i adjust gridview columns width after binding data?

```
        myConnect = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
        myConnect.Open();

        try
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM report_data WHERE user = @user";

            MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnect);
            mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            gvRecords.DataSource = dt;
            gvRecords.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }
```

Below is the code in aspx

```
    <div>
        <asp:GridView CssClass="gridview" ID="gvRecords" runat="server" OnDataBound="gvRecords_DataBound">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

And my css data

```
.gridview tr td {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.gridview tr th {
padding: 5px;}
```

I have also try this way but not working

```
    protected void gvRecords_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvRecords.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
        gvRecords.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
        gvRecords.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        gvRecords.Columns[3].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
        gvRecords.Columns[4].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
    }
```

the columns width generate by AutoGenerateColumns can't fit the data.
[image]

After i add width in css, the columns width change. look better then before.

```
.gridview tr td {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
width: 100px;}
```

[image]

But is there anyway to adjust column width individual?

Comment: What do you see in the browser. The css rule which you are creating is applied or not?

Comment: Above image is what I got in chrome browser and css file work good.

Comment: You may take reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition) or type to use `! important` in css. Not sure but you can also try `gvRecords.Columns[0].Attributes.add("style","150px !important");`

Comment: I try gvRecords.Columns[0].Attributes.add("style","150px !important"). but got error on Attributes property.

Comment: not sure about the syntax but there should be a way to add style to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rather then setting it at runtime you can use the css as below

```
.gridview tr td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}


// second td
.gridview tr td+td {
   width:50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's work. Although the code looks very heavy. I make a lot tr td+td+td+td...etc.

Comment: @TYS if you are using CSS 3 here is a reference which can help you to optimize the css a bit. https://support.awesome-table.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001393209-Add-style-to-specific-columns-or-rows-in-your-Table-app

Answer (score 0):

Add a .cs file to your head-section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css" />
```

with the style :

```
.mytable { width: 100%; }
```

And on your component:

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mytable"
```

Comment: I did this, but nothing change. I think my GridView original width is 100%.