# asp.net showdeletebutton

Tags: asp.net

gridview:

```
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="false" />
```

How to change visibility programatically from Page_load method?

Answer (score 0):

See the following question and answers for a couple of different options:

[Conditionally hide CommandField or ButtonField in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview)