# Disable a buttonfield for a particular user in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This might get a little confusing but I will try my best to explain and would appreciate any help.I have a gridview like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="936px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" style="text-align: center" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward(Rs)" SortExpression="Reward" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAllotted" HeaderText="Time(Min)" SortExpression="TimeAllotted" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PosterName" HeaderText="Uploader" SortExpression="PosterName" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Perform Task" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"  ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true">
            <ControlStyle BackColor="#CC6600" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
```

When I click on the buttonfield of a particular row, I get directed to a new page which asks me to perform some task.
I want to disable the 'perform task' buttonfield for that particular user whenever a task is performed.

How can I do that?

Comment: create column which maintain status of your tasks in database TaskStatus on this you can enable or disable your buttons

Comment: but how would i manage it for individual user logins??

Comment: You need to disable the `Perform Task` button if `PosterName` refers the current user, right? Or to enable/disable `PerformTask` column at all, depending on the current user identity?

Comment: @nativehr - I want to disable the PerformTask buttonfield for a particular user.not all the button but only the one's which he has clicked.

Comment: You can write some code-behind to decide if user should view or not the button. Check out this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview

Comment: @nativehr I have a code written for the buttonfield,i cannot change it to button.So what else can i do to hide the buttonfield on some ondition?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...>
    Other settings
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var button = (Button) e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0];
        button.Enabled = CanCurrentUserViewButton();
    }
}

private bool CanCurrentUserViewButton()
{
    //Logic...
}
```