# Conditionally Hide Delete Button in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have an ASP .NET Datagrid in which I am trying to hide the delete and edit button columns if a certain condition is true (say, the value in one of the columns is X). I found a solution that is exactly what I need here;

[Conditionally hide CommandField or ButtonField in Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview)

But it is for a GridView. I have not been able to find anything similar for a Datagrid, and I am not able to implement that solution. Does anyone have a solution similar to the one linked above, but for data grids? Thanks!

Comment: try to cast datagrid to viewgrid!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use same solution for datagrid also:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" CommandName="Reject" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Age") > 35 ? 1 : 0 %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside using the `DataBinder.Eval`, which is much simpler approach, you could also use the `GridHeaderText' to hide the columns.

See [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11043/Hide-DataGrid-Columns-via-HeaderText) for more on how to hide `DataGrid` columns via `HeaderText`