# Conditionally hide DeleteButton in GridViewCommandColumn

Tags: vb.net, aspxgridview

I have ASPxGridView to view a list of records. From the view, I create a delete column and want it to show a delete button whenever the record does have a satisfy condition. The code below:

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn Caption="Delete" VisibleIndex="1" Width="30px"
                meta:resourcekey="GridViewCommandColumnResource1">
                <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                </DeleteButton>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

So I focus on the Visible attribute of DeleteButton. The condition must return a boolean value so it knows when to show and hide the delete button. Below is an example how to implement this:

```
<DeleteButton Visible='<%# ShowHide(Eval("Active")) %>'>
                </DeleteButton>
```

in VB Code:

```
Protected Function ShowHide(Active As Boolean) As Boolean
    Return Active
End Function
```

So the function need to return a True value if **Active** is True, and False value if **Active** is False. In other words, I do trigger a function in code behind on every record to make it show the delete button if record does have a satisfy condition. But I got an error message in the end:

```
Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewCommandColumnButton does not have a DataBinding event.
```

I stuck there and don't know other way to do this. Please help me with this.

Comment: Follow the link here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview

Comment: Thanks. But this question focus on aspxgridview but not aspgridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a night to research on this, I have find a new way to solve this issue:

This block of code from aspx file within an ASPxGridView:

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn Caption="Delete" VisibleIndex="1" Width="30px"
                meta:resourcekey="GridViewCommandColumnResource1">
                <DeleteButton Visible='True'><!--TRI - 20160329 Please make sure the Visible attribute always True-->
                </DeleteButton>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

From the code behide, I implement an initial method to handle a trigger on DeleteButton:

```
Protected Sub xgv_CommandButtonInitialize(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCommandButtonEventArgs) Handles xgv.CommandButtonInitialize
    If e.ButtonType = DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ColumnCommandButtonType.Delete Then
        If sender.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "Active") = True Then
            e.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The method will handle the DeleteButton by checking the **Active** value on Command Button Initialize. If the **Active** is True, it will hide the DeleteButton and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could either handle the `ASPxClientGridView.CustomButtonClick Event` as shown here : [Link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_CustomButtonClicktopic)  or Place your custom control into `GridViewDataColumn.DataItemTemplate`  : [Link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewDataColumn_DataItemTemplatetopic)

Comment: The event is handled after user's click. But how about the event to handle on first loading of the view?